# Prove : n * log(n) + m * log(m) < n * m

Tags: logarithms, computational-complexity

How do I prove complexity `n * log(n) + m * log(m)` is faster than `n * m`

In other words, how do I prove?

$N  \cdot \log_2(N) + M \cdot \log_2(M) < NM$

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. Take m = log(n). Then, both sides have the same asymptotic growth rate.

Comment: Maybe is easy to study $\frac{\log (n)}{m}+\frac{\log (m)}{n}$. If $n$ is small and $m$ big, the inequality that you try to prove is not true. But if, for example, $n=O(m^{k})$ for some $k$ fixed, then when $m\to\infty$, $\frac{\log (n)}{m}+\frac{\log (m)}{n}\to 0$ and the inequality is true.